# How to prove the following elementary lemma IV 2.3 in Complex Analysis by Eberhand Freitag as my idea or using other better methods?

Tags: complex-analysis

The elementary lemma is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8oyu.png)
where the $E_k(z)$ is the *Weierstrass elementary factors* at the top of the picture. My idea is to emulate the proof of the common version, which is proving that
$|E_k(z) - 1| \le |z|^{k+1}$, $n = 0,1, \cdots$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| \le 1$ by using
$$ |E_k(z) - 1| \le |z|\int_0^1 |E_k'(tz)| \mathrm{d}t \le -|z|^{k + 1} \int_0^1 E_k'(t)\mathrm{d}t, \quad |z| \le 1,$$
denoted by $(*)$. So I tried to use
$$|E_k(z)^m - 1| \le |z|^m \left(\int_0^1 |E_k'(tz)| \mathrm{d}t\right)^m$$
to prove the Lemma IV 2.3, but I failed. Is it possible to imitate $(*)$ to prove this lemma? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E_k(z)=e^{-g_k(z)}, g_k:=\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty z/n.$ If $2|z|\le 1, |g_k(z)|=|z^{k+1}(1/(k+1)+\dots)|\le 2|z^{k+1}|.$ $|E_k(z)^m-1|=|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-mg_k(z))^n/n!|\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty |(-mg_k(z))^n/n!|\le 2m|z^{k+1}|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2m|z^{k+1}|)^{n-1} \le 4m|z|^{k+1}.$

Comment: Thanks for answering this question, but I think you might first need to think about what you're writing

Comment: Hello, I checked your proof again on my phone and found it to be correct. Because I read your answer on my computer this morning, there was something wrong with the formatting of the display, so I mistakenly thought you had given the wrong proof. I apologize for this and thank you.

Comment: May I ask how to get the last inequality please?

Comment: @mio I realized now that it was not correct. It should be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(-mg_k(z))^n/n!|\le 2m|z^{k+1}|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2m|z^{k+1}|)^{n-1}/n! \le 2m|z^{k+1}|(e-1)\le 4m|z|^{k+1}.$

Comment: @Acrobatic Now everything goes well, thanks for your response.